# Redis cache very slow on Magento 2.4.6

Tags: magento2, cache, redis, magento2-cloud

I had a considerable increase in cache growth quickly and my Redis cache slowed down.
Adobe recommended to enabled L2 cache.

What's it and how to enable it?

Answer (score 0):

L2 cache is a cache using the CPU's cores. But it is still the Redis you know.

To enable it, you need to configure your [Stale cache options](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/cache/level-two-cache.html?lang=en#stale-cache-options) like below or your `env.php`:

```php
'cache' => [
    'frontend' => [
        'default' => [
            'backend' => '\\Magento\\Framework\\Cache\\Backend\\RemoteSynchronizedCache',
            'backend_options' => [
                'remote_backend' => '\\Magento\\Framework\\Cache\\Backend\\Redis',
                'remote_backend_options' => [
                    'persistent' => 0,
                    'server' => 'localhost',
                    'database' => '0',
                    'port' => '6379',
                    'password' => '',
                    'compress_data' => '1',
                ],
                'local_backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_File',
                'local_backend_options' => [
                    'cache_dir' => '/dev/shm/'
                ],
                'use_stale_cache' => false,
            ],
            'frontend_options' => [
                'write_control' => false,
            ],
        ],
         'stale_cache_enabled' => [
            'backend' => '\\Magento\\Framework\\Cache\\Backend\\RemoteSynchronizedCache',
            'backend_options' => [
                'remote_backend' => '\\Magento\\Framework\\Cache\\Backend\\Redis',
                'remote_backend_options' => [
                    'persistent' => 0,
                    'server' => 'localhost',
                    'database' => '0',
                    'port' => '6379',
                    'password' => '',
                    'compress_data' => '1',
                ],
                'local_backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_File',
                'local_backend_options' => [
                    'cache_dir' => '/dev/shm/'
                ],
                'use_stale_cache' => true,
            ],
            'frontend_options' => [
                'write_control' => false,
            ],
        ]
    ],
    'type' => [
        'default' => ['frontend' => 'default'],
        'layout' => ['frontend' => 'stale_cache_enabled'],
        'block_html' => ['frontend' => 'stale_cache_enabled'],
        'reflection' => ['frontend' => 'stale_cache_enabled'],
        'config_integration' => ['frontend' => 'stale_cache_enabled'],
        'config_integration_api' => ['frontend' => 'stale_cache_enabled'],
        'full_page' => ['frontend' => 'stale_cache_enabled'],
        'translate' => ['frontend' => 'stale_cache_enabled']
    ],
],
```

Take a look at the [Redis preload](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/cache/redis/redis-pg-cache.html?lang=en#redis-preload-feature) and [parallel](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/cache/redis/redis-pg-cache.html?lang=en#parallel-generation) features. If you need to validate the changes, you can run these commands:

```
redis-cli ping;
redis-cli monitor;
```